# Should the main chatroom be unfrozen?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I have noticed that the room [theory salon](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9446/theory-salon) was recently [frozen for inactivity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9446/2023/6/6).
As far as I can tell, among the rooms [associated with this site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=cstheory.stackexchange.com), this is the room that got the most activity - so perhaps it is not a stretch if I called it the main chatroom.

Basically, that means that the room wasn't actually used that much - so one could say that it probably won't be missed.
OTOH, considering the current events (the moderators' strike), I would not be surprised if some users might be interested in discussing related issues in chat, too.

- Should this chatroom be unfrozen? (Or perhaps it is better to leave it frozen - until somebody asks for unfreezing because they have something to discuss there?)
- If the room is frozen again, was is the best course of action? (Should one flag some post here on meta to get attention of the mods from Theoretical Computer Science? Would it be better to ask for assistance elsewhere, as [suggested here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room/70201#70201)?)